# Visual Studio Code does no longer compile Java

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I was using VSCode for compiling and debugging of simple Java programms. It worked great. Just press F5, enter your main class and press F5 again.
Sadly since I restarted my pc a few days ago, VSCode will no longer run any of my programms. Even previosly working stuff does no longer run.

I'm using these extensions: Debugger for Java, Language Suport for Java.

Every Time I press F5 I will get a error message:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorld
```

I've tried everything. I deinstalled and reinstalled VSCode and Java completely (including all temp-files, caches and settings). I followed every troubleshooting guide but I can't get it to work anymore.

My code:

```
/**
 * HelloWorld
 */
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Debug (Launch) - Current File",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "HelloWorld"
        }
    ]
}
```

Language Support for Java log:

```
[Error - 10:47:04] 12.10.2019, 10:47:04 
null
org.eclipse.jface.text.BadLocationException
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.ListLineTracker.getLineOffset(ListLineTracker.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractLineTracker.getLineOffset(AbstractLineTracker.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.AbstractDocument.getLineOffset(AbstractDocument.java:876)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.filebuffers.SynchronizableDocument.getLineOffset(SynchronizableDocument.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.WorkspaceDiagnosticsHandler.convertRange(WorkspaceDiagnosticsHandler.java:361)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.WorkspaceDiagnosticsHandler.toDiagnostic(WorkspaceDiagnosticsHandler.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.WorkspaceDiagnosticsHandler.lambda$3(WorkspaceDiagnosticsHandler.java:322)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.WorkspaceDiagnosticsHandler.toDiagnosticsArray(WorkspaceDiagnosticsHandler.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.WorkspaceDiagnosticsHandler.publishDiagnostics(WorkspaceDiagnosticsHandler.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.WorkspaceDiagnosticsHandler.publishDiagnostics(WorkspaceDiagnosticsHandler.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ls.core.internal.handlers.JDTLanguageServer$1.run(JDTLanguageServer.java:266)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)

[Error - 10:47:24] 12.10.2019, 10:47:24 Error occured while building workspace. Details: 
 message: Preview features enabled at an invalid source release level 12, preview can be enabled only at source level 13; code: 2098258; resource: C:/Users/Johannes/Desktop/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.java;
```

EDIT:
The solution mentiond in the comments worked.
Just update to JDK 13 and it will work again.

Comment: Here are some more informations about my system. Mabe they help.


Windows: 10.0.17134;
VSCode: 1.39.1;
JDK: 12.0.2

Comment: this is what google gave me https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/1086 seems like you need to update your jdk installation

Comment: try to add  `"vmArgs": "--enable-preview" ` to your Launch.json